# Does Analyzer have any effect of IndexWriter.Optimize()?

Tags: lucene

If a different analyzer is passed through IndexWriterConfig to IndexWriter during optimization, will it result in any issues?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific reason for you to do that?

Comment: Not that I'm going to do that. I just wanted to confirm that analyzer will not have any effect if I open IndexWriter only for optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, as analyzers are only used when analyzing/parsing a document, which does not happen during optimization.